# Are there any Ramadan greetings?

Tags: expressions

Is there a traditional or common greeting for Ramadan?

People who celebrate Christmas routinely wish each other "Merry Christmas". At Hanukkah we say "Happy Hanukkah," etc. Do Moslems have a greeting for Ramadan? Do they wish each other "Happy Ramadan" or "Joyous Ramadan" or something similar?

Comment: Is this really about English?

Comment: I'm looking for an English phrase. I thought that made it about English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two that I found after a quick Google search:

- *Ramadan Kareem* (Noble Ramadan)
- *Ramadan Mubarak* (Blessed Ramadan)